# Finding the equation of the sphere that passes through a circle and a point

Tags: analytic-geometry, spheres

The problem is the following:
I am given a circle by the equations $$x^2+y^2+z^2+2ax+2by+2cz+d=0, Ax+By+Cz+D=0$$ (The first equation is a sphere, the second one a plane, so as I understand the plane cuts the sphere so we get a circle). I have to find the equation of a sphere that passes through the given circle and contains the point $(x_0;y_0;z_0)$, which does not belong to the given plane.

The answer is $$(Ax_0+By_0+Cz_0+D)(x^2+y^2+z^2+2ax+2by+2cz+d)-(x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2+2ax_0+2by_0+2cz_0+d)(Ax+By+Cz+D)=0$$
I don't understand how this can be the answer. Why do we have to pug in that point then subtract? I tried rewriting the equation of the given sphere so that I can find the center and the radius, but nothing happened. Could you please give me some hints or methods to approach this problem?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I know that the equation of a sphere is: $\Sigma: \, x^2+y^2+z^2+ax+by+cz+d=0$ without the $2$.

Comment: @Sebastiano The problem gives the 2 for some reason...

Comment: I have thinked that the $2$ is given to have the center of the sphere $(a,b,c)$ instead of the classic $(a/2,b/2,c/2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

The idea is: any solution of the system
$$f=0\\
g=0$$
is also a solution of $f+ \lambda g =0$ for any $\lambda$. So now consider the sphere
of equation
$$x^2 + y^2 +z^2 + 2 a x + 2 b y + 2 c z + d + \lambda(A x + B y + C z + D)=0$$
that passes through the point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$. $\lambda$ can be easily obtained now.

Comment: It is also my answer that I am writing. ahahah. $\ddot \smile$.

Comment: @orangeskid Thank you

Comment: @Sebastiano:  Yes, it is a very nice idea. For instance, it can show how to get all the conics passing through $4$ points. We know $2$ of them ( $3$ in fact -- they are all product of equations of two lines), so they are linear combinations of them. I like Salmon - Conic sections for nice explanations.

Comment: @Britanica: You are very welcome!

Comment: @orangeskid May I ask what Salmon is?

Comment: @orangeskid Very kind, mine are just fond memories of when I was at university. Quadrics after so many years I remember something. My prof. was crazy about spheres in a good way.

Comment: @Britanica It is a book :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano I thought it's some sort of a youtube channel XDXD (like 3blue1brown). I'll check it out!

Comment: @Britanica: Yes, it is a book by Rev. George Salmon, you can find it here https://archive.org/details/atreatiseonconi00unkngoog   lots of interesting things

Comment: @Sebastiano:  Yes, quadrics are indeed very interesting. Btw, Salmon also has a book about three dimensional geometry, it looks very interesting  https://archive.org/details/atreatiseonanal02salmgoog/page/n8/mode/2up

Comment: @Britanica Please, can you switch the green check mark to orangeskid? For me it is a question of justice :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano:  You are too kind... I really appreciated it!   btw, I noticed there are more editions of Salmon's book on the archive, latest would be in two volumes.

Comment: @orangeskid I think, and I also believe as a Catholic, that in this short life you have to leave something good, that comes from the heart without getting anything in return. I don't know how long I will live but the memory of having done something good for others makes me happy. And then I use the criterion with you, with other users, with my students, to be sincere and objective. Your answer is more fluid and you have to be honest. I always wish you the best.

Comment: @Sebastiano: So true!  And I always wish you the best too..

Answer (score 4):

Consider the circumference $\mathcal C$ of equations

\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2+z^2+2ax+2by+2cz+d=0 &\\
Ax+By+Cz+D=0
\end{cases}

A sphere containing $\mathcal C$ is therefore $\mathcal S_1$ of equation $x^2+y^2+z^2+2ax+2by+2cz+d=0$.

Any other sphere $\mathcal S$ containing $\mathcal C$ must have an equation of the form:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2+2a'x+2b'y+2c'z+d'=0 \tag 1$$

such that
$$\scriptstyle x^2+y^2+z^2+2a'x+2b'y+2c'z+d'-(x^2+y^2+z^2+2ax+2by+2cz+d)
=\lambda (Ax+By+Cz+D) \tag 2\\
$$ where $\lambda \in \Bbb R$.

If, for example, we want to determine the sphere containing $\mathcal C$ and passing through $P_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ we must choose $λ$ such that the assigned point satisfies the
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+2ax+2by+2cz+d-\lambda (Ax+By+Cz+D)=0$$

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have to think a lot about this problem )) It's more complicated than I thought

Comment: @Britanica You're welcome. :-) and mine was only happy memories.

Comment: @Britanica I am kindly asking you for a favour. Could you please give the green tick to the user who preceded me by a few seconds? And then his answer is simpler and similar to mine. I thank you.

Comment: no problem, thank you))